# Delete entire rows in a Table from sqlite database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have to delete some rows in a TABLE_LOCATION. I am using below code, but it is not deleting. anyone know the solution.

```
public void deleteData(String favouriteOrNot, String vaType) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_LOCATION + " WHERE " + this.FavouriteOrNot + "='" + favouriteOrNot + "' AND " + this.VaType + "='" + vaType + "';";
        db.execSQL(deleteQuery);
}
```

Comment: it have to delete multiple row's

Answer (score 1):

**try this way**

For Delete the entire table

```
public int DELETE_TABLE(String tableName){
        return myDataBase.delete(tableName, null, null);
    }
```

**or**

For delete the multiple entries

```
public int DELETE_TABLE_WITH_SELECTION(String tableName, String selection){
return myDataBase.delete(tableName, selection, null);
    }
```

here `myDataBase` is SQLiteDatabase.

```
selection = this.FavouriteOrNot + "='" + favouriteOrNot + "' AND " + this.VaType + "='" + vaType + "'";
```

Comment: i don't want to delete table, i need to delete some row's